# Do I need to import some namespace to my view to use Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Do I need to import some namespace to my view to use Ajax.BeginForm?  I'm successfully using AjaxActionLink in other parts of my program with no problem.  Now i'm trying to change my Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm.  Started with a simple beginform like this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",  new AjaxOptions { name =”someName” }))
```

and got an error message that states

```
 System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper<MyModel> does not contain a definition for BeginForm…
```

I've seen this version of ajax begin form all over the place so I'm thinking that it must be something that my view is missing.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: YOU ARE USING WRONG PARAMETER FOR AJAX OPTION SEE BELOW IMAGE]

YOU ARE USING WRONG PARAMETER FOR AJAX OPTION SEE IMAGE
AND AJAX.BEGINFORM IS EXTENTION METHOD FOR MVC. NO NEED TO IMPORT ANY NAMESPACE.